# How to push data in array stored in the Firebase using angularfire2?

Tags: arrays, database, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm using angularfire2 to store data in the firebase database. I need to add data to an array stored in the database to be like this:

`places:
   0:"new Item"
   1:"new Item",
   2:"new Item"
   .
   .
   .`

and so on and that what i need.
But in my case the data look like this:

[image]

this is my code:

`this.user = this.db.list("/Users/"+ this.currentUserId+'/places');
 this.user.push(["new Item"]);`

> When the user enter new place, I need new data enter to the array and not a new array inserted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing an array, try to push an object instead. Example:

```
this.user.push({description: "new Item"});
```

Comment: hi, it looks like `
places:
      asdjasdjdjasas
           description:"new Item"`

Comment: I need the key to be generate by the firebase 0  1 2

Comment: and exactly under  the places title

Comment: Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html